# Multiple loot tables in one datapack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

So I have a slight issue with loot tables, I created three separate tables and whenever I go in and give myself the chest variant of the loot table it seems to sometimes not work on the others. So for the first one I am calling it "Tier 1" and giving it to myself using the command

```
/give @s chest{BlockEntityTag:{LootTable:"random:blocks/tier1"},display:{Name:'{"text":"Tier 1","italic":false,"color":"gold"}'}} 1
```

The name shouldn't matter but when I change this to tier2 it doesn't work although they are both located in the same place. How do I fix this?

Loot table 1: https://pastebin.com/tfPScrE2
Loot table 2: https://pastebin.com/Js29saWE
Loot table 3: https://pastebin.com/WcaXqmeP

All three are located inside a folder named "blocks" in my random folder in the datapack, its also under the corresponding loot_tables folder. As that was needed to create the custom loot tables. These are just Proof of concept and will be changed but they don't all work at the same time when I run the command.

Comment: Since your question is about something that happens with one loot table but not another, we would need to see thoes loot tables. Please paste them into your question.

Comment: Oh, you edited the question. That doesn't notify me. Did you verify that `\"` in `'` in `"` works? It probably does, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It does. But "`set_data`" doesn't exist.

Comment: And that's apparently the only problem. Writing answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`set_damage`" doesn't exist.

If you want to set durability (now the NBT tag "`Damage`" instead of metadata, which no longer exists), you can use "`set_damage`" (but not on coal).

If you want to set NBT, you can use "`set_nbt`".